# Выборка строк из файлов

Tags: bash

Господа, есть ли быстрый способ выбрать строки, которые дублируются в 2-х файлах?

Напиример:

file1.txt

```
MariaFeudorIvanNikolay
```

file2.txt

```
DmitryElenaAntonMariaEvgenyIvan
```

На выходе нужно получить

```
MariaIvan
```

Какое либо компактное и быстрое решение, может быть можно через diff?

Comment: Не сразу понял, что строки вы явно не разделили пулучилось 2 файла с одной строкой кемлкейса.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`awk` пробежит по каждой строке первого файла, отыскивая её с помощью `grep` во втором.

Upd. Не понимаю, почему каждая стрка выводится дважды. Гуру шелла, хелп! Как-то так:<code><strike>cat file1.txt | awk '/^.+$/ { "grep "$0" file2.txt" | getline cmdout; print cmdout}'</strike></code>

**Upd. 2**: Вот работающее решение. Спасибо @Dmitry_Chubarov за фикс с дублями.

```
cat file1.txt | awk {' "grep "$0" file2.txt" | getline cmdout; if ( cmdout != "" )print cmdout ; cmdout=""; '}
```

**Upd. 3**: неимоверно усложнил я, конечно. Верный ответ см. от [[@dik-m](/users/1451/dik-m)](/users/1451/dik-m): все решается одним `grep` с ключем `-f`.

Comment: Чтобы избежать лишних строк в выводе, нужно обнулять шаблон `cmdout` на каждой итерации и проверять его на пустоту. `cat file1.txt | awk '/^.+$/ { "grep "$0" file2.txt" | getline cmdout ;  if (cmdout != "" ) {print cmdout ; } ; cmdout="" }'`

Answer (score 5):

Вы можете использовать команду `join`. Поставленную задачу она замечательно решает, хотя может больше.

```
join file1.txt file2.txt
```

Команда выдаст предупреждение о том, что следует предварительно отсортировать файлы и строки, встречающиеся в обеих фалах

```
:~> join file1.txt file2.txt join: file 2 is not in sorted orderjoin: file 1 is not in sorted orderMariaIvan
```

Дополнение (по совету [PocketSam](http://admin.hashcode.ru/users/1054/pocketsam)): Файлы можно отсортировать командой `sort`. Следующая строчка сортирует один из файлов, выполняет слияние и удаляет временный файл.

```
:~> FILE2=$( mktemp ) && sort file2.txt > $FILE2 && \sort file1.txt | join - $FILE2 && rm $FILE2
```

выводит:

```
IvanMaria
```

Comment: Хочу добавить, что отсортировать можно с помощью команды sort.

Comment: @PocketSam Спасибо, добавил указание про сортировку.

Answer (score 4):

Утилита [comm](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comm)

```
[s@pandora6 /tmp]$ cat _file1.txtFeudorIvanMariaNikolay[s@pandora6 /tmp]$ cat _file2.txtAntonDmitryElenaEvgenyIvanMaria[s@pandora6 /tmp]$ comm -1 -2 _file1.txt _file2.txtIvanMaria
```

Answer (score 4):

По моему всё на много проще:

так

```
grep -f file1.txt file2.txt
```

или так

```
grep -f file2.txt file1.txt
```

результат одинаков

```
IvanMaria
```

Comment: Вы правы. С awk + grep я явно намудрил и усложнил.

Comment: Спасибо! Действительно так проще.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ comm --help
Usage: comm [OPTION]... FILE1 FILE2
Compare sorted files FILE1 and FILE2 line by line.


$ cat file*                                          
123
456
789
123                                                    
456
789
987
$ ls file*
file1  file2                                            
$ comm -12 file1 file2
123
456
789
```